# OnClickListener к RecycleView

Tags: java, android

Как отловить нажатие на RecycleView?
setOnClickListener не работает. Пробовал обернуть его слоем и отлавливать клик на слой - тоже не работает.

**Нужен клик именно по всей области RecycleView, не по какому-то элементу**

Comment: Вы делаете что-то ОЧЕНЬ странное! Зачем вам тогда нужен `RyceclerView`? Давайте сюда код и разметку того, что не работает.

Comment: мой recycle это чат. В нем содержится всего 1 textview с самим сообщением. ( всего 50 сообщений макс. )
По клику на область recycle ( чата ) мне нужно открывать клавиатуру.
Что в таком случае я должен использовать для этого вместо recycle?

Comment: а в чем проблема ловить клик по любому элементу списка и показывать клавиатуру тогда? клик по RV отлавливать это как уже было написано очень неправильная идея

Comment: с этим проблем нет. 
просто я думал наоборот - не правильно ловить клик на элемент когда мне надо клик куда-угодно